# How to analyze mixed versions of .NET using SonarScanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

**Version**
SonarQube8.5 Community

**Scanner**
sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.10.0.19059-net46.
sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net5.0.

In a single git repository we have two .NET 5 solutions and one .NET 4.7.2 solution and one .NETStandard 2.0 solution. The .NETStandard project is referenced by all other .NET projects (.NET 5 & .NET 4.7.2)

```
/MyGitRepo 
  /Common Solution       
     /Common.csproj (NetStandard 2.0) 
  /Solution1 (.NET 5) 
     All projects are .NET5.     
     References Common.csproj 
  /Solution2 (.NET 5)    
     All projects are .NET5 .      
     References Common.csproj.      
  /Solution3 (.NET Framework 4.7.2)      
     All projects are 4.7.2.     
     References Common.csproj
```

I understand that .Net 4.7.2 and .Net 5 have different scanners. I would like to know, If I analyze solutions using their respective scanners but point both scanners to the same SonarQube project using same project key in both scanners, will it work? or will the second scans overwrite the result of the first scan?

```
--Scan NET 5 solutions dotnet
 "C:\SonarQubeScanners\net5\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:"MyProjectKey" /d:sonar.host.url="http://sonarqube.xyz.com" /d:sonar.login="myloginkey"      

  dotnet build Solution1.sln" 

  dotnet build Solution2.sln" 

"C:\SonarQubeScanners\net5\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end /d:sonar.login="myloginkey" 
    
    
--Scan NET 4.7.2 solution   
C:\SonarQubeScanners\net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"MyProjectKey" /d:sonar.host.url="http://sonarqube.xyz.com" /d:sonar.login="myloginkey" 
    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "Solution3.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release 
    
C:\SonarQubeScanners\net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="myloginkey"
```

I am trying to avoid creating two separate SonarQube projects, One for .NET 5 solutions and Second for .NET 4.7.2 Solution.
*(reposting [question](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/analyze-mixed-versions-of-net/41087) here on SO for broader audience)*

Answer (score 0):

Doing two analyses with the same key will make them overwrite each other. However you should be able to use only one scanner to analyze both projects, as [documented](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/):

> The flavor used to compile the Scanner for .NET (either .NET Framework, .NET Core or .NET) is independent of the .NET version the project you want to analyze has been built with.

I would just call *begin* once, compile both projects and then run *end* once.